# Powershell Compare the Lastwritedate and delete the File/s

Tags: powershell, compare, delete-file

i really want to "end" this script. I already created a little script but with that one im only able to delete the files from the first dictionary that i enter.

The script shoud compare two folders and if there are files with the same name i want to choose if i want to delete the older version of it or the newer one.

//Edit

```
$path1 = Read-Host "Name the 1st Path"
$path2 = Read-Host "Name the 2nd Path"
$Folder1 = Get-ChildItem -Path $pfad1 -Recurse 
$Folder2 = Get-ChildItem -Path $pfad2 -Recurse
Write-Host "####################################"
Write-Host ( Get-ChildItem $pfad1,$pfad2 ).count
Write-Host "Files are in the folder"
Write-Host "####################################"
$frage = Read-Host "Are you sure you want to delete the files YES / NO ?"


if ($frage -eq $NO) { "Files stay " ; exit }
else {
        Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Folder1 -DifferenceObject $Folder2 
 -IncludeEqual |
            Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "=="} | 
            ForEach-Object { 
            Remove-Item $_.InputObject.FullName | where { $_.lastwritetime -lt $altdate  } 
            }
                }
```

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far and limit your question to a specific problem. SO is not a code writing page

Comment: Done, and ty for the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the size of your folders this may not be the most performant way of doing this. But it does work.

```
$files = $folder1 + $folder2
$files | 
    Group-Object name | 
    Foreach-Object {
        $_.Group | 
        Sort-Object LastWriteTime | 
        Select-Object -Last 1 
    } | 
    Remove-Item -Force
```

ok. Iv'e reworked my original answer to address some of its short comings. This answer gives you the ability to see what will be deleted and kept by using the testing code. I know I could have used a proper verbose switch and whatif functionality but this seemed easier. Ive addressed the ordering issue and the problem where non duplicate items would be deleted.

```
$folder1 = 'c:\temp\reports1' 
$folder2 = 'c:\temp\reports2'


function Get-FilesForDeletion ($folder1, $folder2, [switch] $verbose){
    $files1 = Get-ChildItem $folder1
    $files2 = Get-ChildItem $folder2

    $files = $files1 + $files2

    $i = ($files | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Directory | Measure-Object -Maximum -Property Length).Maximum

    $files | 
        Group-Object name | 
        Where-Object Count -gt 1 |
        Foreach-Object {    
            $process = $_

            $deleteMe = $process.Group | 
                    Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | 
                    Select-Object -Last 1 

            if($verbose){
                Write-Host "Processing $($process.Group.Name)..."

                $keepThese = $process.Group | 
                    Sort-Object LastWriteTime | 
                    Select-Object -Skip 1 

                Write-Host "  - Delete  $(($deleteMe.Directory.FullName).PadRight($i)) - LastWriteTime $($deleteMe.lastWriteTime) "

                $keepThese | ForEach-Object {
                    Write-Host "  - Keep    $(($_.Directory.FullName).PadRight($i)) - LastWriteTime $($_.lastWriteTime) "
                }              

                write-host " "
                write-host " "
            }

            $deleteMe
        } 
}

# testing code
#Get-FilesForDeletion -folder1 $folder1 -folder2 $folder2 -verbose | Out-Null

Get-FilesForDeletion -folder1 $folder1 -folder2 $folder2 -verbose | Remove-Item
```

Comment: First time i tried, it worked. Now it doesnt work anymore. It only delets the newest file and doesnt compare the file names...

Comment: Oops you need a where-object {$_.count -gt 1} in between the group and for each. It’s just finding the first record

Comment: shoud look like this?
`code $path1 = Read-Host "Name the 1st Path"
$path2 = Read-Host "Name the 2nd Path"
$folder1 = Get-ChildItem -Path $path2 -Recurse 
$folder2 = Get-ChildItem -Path $path1 -Recurse 
$files = $folder1 + $folder2
$files |
        Group-Object name |
        where-object {$_.count -gt 1} 
        ForEach-Object {
        $_.Group | 
        Sort-Object LastWriteTime | 
        Select-Object -Last 1 
    } | 
        Remove-Item -Force`

Comment: Looks like you missed a pipe operator | before the foreach. The pipe operator is used to pipe output from one function to the next. This makes it quite easy to test your code. Split your script up testing as you go e.g. function 1, functions 1 + 2, functions 1 + 2 + 3, etc. You will have script that woks in no time.

Comment: Ah yes i got you! Thanks it works now. But just one little thing now. It does not compare the dates of the files. It just the delets to duplicated files from the first folder you call...

Comment: e.g I have a folder called 1 and 2. The files in 2 are older but have the same name like the files from folder 1. If i name the folder 1 in my script first it delets the files from folder 1 but shoud delet the files from folder 2 because they are older.